# Confusion about inability to assign numpy array element using multiple array indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I ran into a bug caused by using multiple sets of brackets to index an array, i.e. using a[i][j] (for various reasons, mostly laziness, which I've now fixed properly). While attempting to assign an element of the array, I found that I was unable to, but I didn't receive any kind of error to tell me why. I am confused as to why I can't do this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(0,50,10)
>>> idx = np.array([1,3,4])
>>> x[idx]
array([10, 30, 40])
>>> x[idx][1]
30
>>> x[idx][1] = 10    #this assignment doesn't work
>>> x[idx][1]
30
```

However, if I instead index the idx array inside the brackets, then it seems to work:

```
>>> x[idx[1]]
30
>>> x[idx[1]] = 100
>>> x[idx[1]]
100
```

Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to explain this is that each `[]` translates into `__getitem__()` call, and each `[]=` is a `__setitem__` call.

```
x[idx][1]= 2
```

is then

```
x.__getitem__(idx).__setitem__(1, 2)
```

If `x.__getitem__(idx)` produces a new array with its own databuffer, the `set` changes that, not `x`.  If on the other hand the `get` produces a `view`, then the change will appear in `x`.

It's important when working with arrays, that you understand the difference between a `view` and `copy`.

Answer (score 2):

Because:

```
x[idx]
```

Creates a *new array object with an independent, underlying buffer*.

So then you *index into that*:

```
[1] = 10
```

Which *does work*, but then you don't keep that new array around, and it is discarded immediately.

Whereas:

```
x[idx[1]] = 100
```

Assigns to some particular index in the existing array object.